# English song with a spiritual creature in it

Tags: music-identification

It's an English song that I watched in VH1 channel around 1-2 years back.

The song has a human being (I remember a mid 20-30 year old girl) in it and a mysterious creature that wanders on a mountain. It looks like a spiritual creature that's mostly transparent and walks on 2 legs.

The creature's resemblance is similar to the Pokemon Gengar but a lot bigger and with a different color(light colored).

The creature is portrayed using graphics/vfx and is definitely not portrayed by an actual person. It doesn't talk or sing during the song.

The person just follows the creature and it keeps wandering in the forest and on the mountains.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Have made some changes and will add extra details the moment I recall them @valorum

Comment: The creature seems to resemble those in the 2009 film *Where the Wild Things Are*. There are unofficial music videos on YouTube, but none of the human characters they feature are adults.

Answer (score 5):

I think this could be Zara Larrson - *Never Forget You*.

It was released 2017 so fits with when you would have seen the video.  In the video she's wondering around a mountain in Iceland with a huge creature who looks like Gengar.

[image: Never Forget You music video screenshot showing the monster]

Comment: This matches quite well but it's worth noting that the OP mentions the creature was _"light coloured"_  and _"mostly transparent"_ but other than that it seems mostly spot on.

Comment: Thanks for adding the pic @TheLethalCarrot.  Yes, I'd thought that too about the creature being lighter / transparent but sometimes our memory plays tricks on us.  The size and shape of the creature, age of the girl, the mountain and when the song was released etc all seem to add up otherwise

Comment: Nope, this is not it. Yes the creature is a bigger than this and is transparent like a soul/spirit. For a change you can ignore the presence of human being for now, but there's definitely a creature.

Comment: I'm gonna describe an exact image from the song.. as the video of the song goes on, the unknown being stands on a mountain and will look very huge. There's sun, blue sky and no sign of any abnormal climate. It walks very slowly on 2 legs and stands there. This scene is probably the end of the song.

Comment: Also the filter in the video gives that nostalgic feel, not the modern video effects used in this video